# Not able to store data in file properly using gob

Tags: file, dictionary, go, gob

When I try to save the map of type `map[mapKey]string` into a file using `gob` encoder, it is not saving string in file.

Here `mapKey` is struct and map value is long json string.

```
type mapKey struct{
    Id1 string
    Id2 string
}
```

And whenever I am use nested map instead of the struct like:

```
var m = make(map[string]map[string]string)
```

It is working fine and saving string properly. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Code to encode, decode and save it in file:

```
func Save(path string, object interface{}) error {
    file, err := os.Create(path)
    if err == nil {
        encoder := gob.NewEncoder(file)
        encoder.Encode(object)
    }
    file.Close()
    return err
}

// Decode Gob file
func Load(path string, object interface{}) error {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err == nil {
        decoder := gob.NewDecoder(file)
        err = decoder.Decode(object)
    }
    file.Close()
    return err
}

func Check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        fmt.Println(line, "\t", file, "\n", e)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: And why you are not using as a nested map. Probably the input is required to be as a nested map.

Comment: @SimoEndre : As per https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action blog , they suggest to use Struct if you have a nested map type structure for mapping.
However I am new to Go and I am not sure whether I can use the struct or not.
It is not giving any compilation error , but it is not saving the long string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing special in encoding a value of type `map[mapKey]string`.

See this very simple working example which uses the specified reader/writer:

```
func save(w io.Writer, i interface{}) error {
    return gob.NewEncoder(w).Encode(i)

}
func load(r io.Reader, i interface{}) error {
    return gob.NewDecoder(r).Decode(i)
}
```

Testing it with an in-memory buffer ([`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer)):

```
m := map[mapKey]string{
    {"1", "2"}: "12",
    {"3", "4"}: "34",
}
fmt.Println(m)

buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
if err := save(buf, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var m2 map[mapKey]string
if err := load(buf, &m2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m2)
```

Output as expected (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vucvCcxySH)):

```
map[{1 2}:12 {3 4}:34]
map[{1 2}:12 {3 4}:34]
```

You have a working code, but know that you have to call `Load()` with a pointer value (else [`Decoder.Decode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Decoder.Decode) wouldn't be able to modify its value).

Also a few things to improve it:

- In your example you are swallowing the `error` returned by [`Encoder.Encode()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Encoder.Encode) (check it and you'll see what the problem is; a common problem is using a struct `mapKey` with no exported fields in which case an error of `gob: type main.mapKey has no exported fields` would be returned).
- Also you should call [`File.Close()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Close) as a deferred function.
- Also if opening the file fails, you should return early and you shouldn't close the file.

This is the corrected version of your code:

```
func Save(path string, object interface{}) error {
    file, err := os.Create(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    return gob.NewEncoder(file).Encode(object)
}

func Load(path string, object interface{}) error {
    file, err := os.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    return gob.NewDecoder(file).Decode(object)
}
```

Testing it:

```
m := map[mapKey]string{
    {"1", "2"}: "12",
    {"3", "4"}: "34",
}
fmt.Println(m)

if err := Save("testfile", m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

var m2 map[mapKey]string
if err := Load("testfile", &m2); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(m2)
```

Output as expected:

```
map[{1 2}:12 {3 4}:34]
map[{1 2}:12 {3 4}:34]
```

Comment: Was going to suggest to check if you are using pointers as icza described here -- among other very good suggestions.